# in laravel 5, which function parameter does the /?page= url argument feed?

Tags: ajax, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

i need to have two different paginators in one page, using ajax to dynamically load the paged content in each of the div's.

the thing that concerns me is where to feed the page argument in my controller, that corresponds to the page number i want to retrieve from the paginator. i don't seem to have sorted that one out, although i have been running through the Builder, Paginator, AbstractPaginator source code thoroughly... guess my code architecture comprehension needs a boost....

the technique that i follow is render() the pager controls, then modify them with jquery in a way that href=/random/route/?page=4 becomes onclick=/random/route/pager-type/4

i have setup the appropriate routes ** /random/route/{pager-type?}/{page-no?} **  but i have no understanding on how to use the page-no argument in extracting the page i am interested in from the pager instance.

thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually you can use Laravel function for example:

```
$posts = Posts::forPage(what_page, how_many_you_want_to_query it out);
```

so if I put `forPage(2, 10)` it will skip first 10 row and query after it with 10 rows.

Behind the scene Laravel will do this when you using `forPage` function:

```
$this->skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)->take($perPage);
```

Comment: i have tried that as well, but the convenience of the render() method that is aware of the begining and end of the collection is the reason i finally chose to go with the Paginator method....